# C++ restricting types in generics (and pointer questions)

Tags: c++, pointers, generics

This question may have more to do with how C++ handles pointers at compile-time, but this came up while learning about generics. I have the following code (which doesn't give me any errors in Visual Studio):

```
class myClass { int x; };

template<typename T>
int myFunc(T obj)
{
    return obj.someMethod();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myClass obj = myClass();
    myFunc(obj);
}
```

Obviously, "myClass" doesn't have someMethod(), but Visual Studio doesn't give me any errors. However, when I change myFunc to this:

```
template<typename T>
int myFunc(T *obj)
{
    return obj->someMethod();
}
```

I do get an error, and I think it's because the compiler checks that myClass doesn't have a someMethod(). Why don't I get the same error with the first block of code?

Comment: Are you sure you tried that exact code?  There is a semicolon missing at the end of the first line.

Comment: The first code is illegal , either you didn't post your exact code; or the code you compiled is not what you thought it was.

Comment: I re-typed the code instead of copying and pasting, but I edited the post to add the semicolon. There was a semicolon originally.

Answer (score 2):

Both passing by value and passing by reference using a pointer fail for me with g++ and clang++
clang++ is version 3.6.1
g++ is version 4.9.2

If you can reproduce this on visual studio, file a bug on their compiler.

Comment: I also checked in Visual Studio and the build fails. @K. Li are you sure you are compiling the proper file?